# iPhone LocationManager - Getting Coordinates at App Start

Tags: iphone, dictionary, locationmanager

I'm getting the location through `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`. It should work when you move (can't really test it in simulator, at least I don't know how) but when I first load the app, the mapview is focused on the whole world, not just my location. Can I anyhow call the method to change the location on first view?
Here is my current code if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/9Sb2xVmE
http://pastebin.com/rh9WB2ca

Comment: You should accept answers to your previous questions before asking new ones...

Comment: You can in the simulator do this, only the map shows Apple HQ. If your devmachine is a MacBook you can take it wherever you want and the simulator will update the location. This is because the simulator uses the same CoreLocation framework Mac OS X uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your using mapkit:**

Have you tried

```
setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: 61.2180556, longitude: -149.9002778};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

[mapView setRegion:region];
```

this should zoom the mapview to your desired size, while maintaining focus on the center.

**If your using CoreLocation:**

Heres a checklist of what might have gone wrong:

- Did you remember to import
- Do you have a location manager (locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];)
- Is the code mentioned within the delegate of the location manager ?

I advise you to go to this page : [Getting location of a iOS device with objective-C](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application) and follow the tutorial bit by bit. That should help you out.

Also, heres the mapkit docs

Best of luck with your project :]

Comment: Hi, yes the setRegion works, but the didUpdateToLocation is not called in the beginning, so I can't get the coords and zoom the map in, so I would like to know a way how to somehow call the didUpdateToLocation in the beginning of the app

Answer (score 0):

we cant able to get the current location by running it in simulator. if you run the application in device it will show the correct location. In simulator it will show the default loaction as califorina(apple head quaters).

Comment: Yes, I know, but the problem is that I want the mapview to zoom in into the location set (default california), but when I first view the map it doesn't zoom in, it stays zoomed away and shows the whole world.